# libstdc++-6 dll errors with opencv

Tags: qt, opencv, runtime-error, codeblocks, libstdc++

Let's start with a bit of history and explanation of my situtation, I'm a french trainee (so sorry for my english, i'll do my best so that you can understand me), I started to write my program with visual studio 2008 and Open CV 2.4.1, after 2 months my C++ program works fine and I now have to do the interface, using Qt.

I first installed an older version of Qt, an SDK that matches with the visual studio 2008 compiler, and I tried to do a very simple first interface with just some pushbutton and information windows to get used to Qt, and I couldn't run this, I had a runtime error form Visual Studio. So, I compiled the same simple program with mingw, and it worked fine. (I did not use opencv at that time).

So then, I started to take some methods from my big program, so I had to add some opencv stuff in the Qt properties, and that is when all crashes. I spent 3 days trying many many "solutions" that I've found on internet, but it doesn't change anything, so now I'm desperate. Here are all the combination I tired :

1) Qt Creator 4 (something) and opencv2.4.1 : my little program compiles fine, but when I ran it, I had the error -1074751515, this is a dll error so I downloaded dependency walkers and it gave me all the dll I had to copy/paste near my .exe, which I did. The error became -1074751511, I couldn't find the exact meaning of that error so I executed manually my .exe and I had an error telling me something about the libstdc++-6.dll (entry point not found or whatever). I uninstalled Qt, and reinstalled it, but nothing changed. So, I downloaded code::blocks, to recompile opencv 2.4.1 with mingw

2) Code::Blocks (the very last version) and opencv2.4.1 : I copied/pasted a very famous and simple program, (the lena.jpg stuff. It compiled, but same error about the libstdc stuff when I ran it so how can I recompile my opencv ?

3) other computer Qt Creator 5.0.2 and opencv 2.4.1 : same error about libstdc

4) on this "other computer" code::blocks and opencv 2.4.5 (5 and not 1) : the lena program still crashes with this libstdc error (entry point could not be found)

And now I'm out of idea.

How can I fix this libstdc++-6 dll issue that crashes everything everywhere ?

If you need to see some code, juste tell me and I'll edit.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using Qt for `MinGW`? If so, have you rebuilt your application and `OpenCV` using `MinGW`?

Comment: Hi ! Sorry for the delay, I've found the solution : opencv 2.4.5 and Qt5 are not compatible, I couldn't even rebuild opencv using code::blocks. So I downloaded the opencv 2.4.2, rebuilt it with code::blocks (mingw), and installed a qt SDK with Qt 4.7.3. It now compiles and runs fine (using the mingw of Qt, and the lib from the rebuilded opencv) =)

Comment: Good find, I wouldn't have thought the libraries were incompatible if both were compiled from source using the same compiler, etc - interesting issue!